# Protractor tests are passing regardless if isDisplayed is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have some E2E tests that are currently passing. I thought this was working as expected, however when i use `browser.sleep()` after inputing data into fields to modify some fields to see if the test will fail when it reaches the expected results.

Our test spec fills out a form, and upon saving the form, we navigate back home to see the name of the form to display in a grid(if the save is successful).

The expected code in our spec is as follows:

```
expect(element.all(mainPO.getScheduled()).isDisplayed());
```

Main PageObject:

```
this.currentScheduledCampaign = by.linkText(scheduledData.scheduledEntity.name);

this.getCurrentScheduledCampaign = function() {
     return this.currentScheduledCampaign;
};
```

scheduledEntity:

```
this.scheduledEntity = {
    name: 'Protractor Test' + ' ' + uuid.v4()
};
```

Why would `.isDisplayed()` returning the protractor test as a fail, even if i remove say the "Protractor Test" from the name during a `browser.sleep()` BEFORE saving the campaign?

I've tried running with `console.log()` on both the `getCurrentScheduledCampaign` and `scheduledData.scheduledEntity.name` and it seems to return the proper expected name being `"Protractor Test [UUID]"` and `"{ using: 'link text', value: 'Protractor Test [UUID]'`.

Comment: I have also pulled out the get method from the expected and replaced it directly with `element.all(by.linkText(scheduledData.scheduledEntity.name)).isDisplayed();` and changed the name during the `browser.sleep()` completely to "test" and the spec still passes

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are missing the `toBe()`/`toEqual()`/... part of the jasmine expectation. There is no assertion being made at all.

Here is how you should check that all the elements in the `ElementArrayFinder` are visible:

```
var elements = element.all(mainPO.getScheduled());
elements.each(function (elm) {
    expect(elm.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Hrm, that still seems to result in the test being a pass regardless of the result. Using `console.log(elm)` seems to act like the code isn't even there. `console.log(elements)` seems to output the expected variable.

Comment: I guess one of the questions i have is how are we passing the `elements` variable into the `elm` parameter option?

Comment: @user249656 we are not passing elements into `each()` - `elm` is a next `ElementFinder` in the  `elements` `ElementArrayFinder`. It is difficult to tell what is currently wrong without being able to reproduce the issue. Is it a public site?